# Using Azure Active Directory as authentication backend for ssh on linux box

Tags: azure, linux, authentication

I used to use on-site active directory (providing pubkey though a custom AD field), but in my new company they are using Azure AD. I don't think my old way would work, did anyone already did this ? If yes any insights would be very kind.